# Hibernate mapping one to one xml

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am working with some old hibernate code, and need to update and create a one to one.

I have a table

```
Table_1
PK table_1_id
FK table_2_id

Table_2
PK table_2_id
```

How do I map these in hibernate XML files so that the relationship is unqiue.. I have tried the

```
<many to one ... unique='true'>
```

but that does not work as it allows two records from table_1 to reference one row from table_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the proper way, as documented in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#assoc-unidirectional-121).

Hibernate will never prevent two records from `table_1` to reference one the same row from `table_2`. That's the role of the unique constraint that you should add on the `table_2_id` column of `table_1`, in the database.

Comment: The unique constraint of "unique" will work but my foreign key column can also be null on initial creation. So i cannot have it set to unqiue=true? or can i?

Comment: Yes, you can. Unique constraints don't care about null values.

Comment: Okay, will test that now... btw do i also need to define the column as as UNIQUE in table creation on the database.

Comment: I don't know which database you use, and what is the exact meaning of a unique column, but if that's how you create a unique constraint on that column, then yes, that's what you must do to ensure it's a one-to-one any not a many-to-one.

Comment: I followed what was in the docs and it still allows me to have more than one row linked, i also tried the following with <many to one> in one file and <one to one> in another.. still no joy

Comment: Have you created a unique constraint in database? As I said twice already, this is the only thing that can guarantee that you don't have two table1 rows pointing at the same table2 row.

Comment: Yes I did but unique constraints in the database (sql sever) do care about nulls, i cannot have more than one row with null in the foreign key. So i have removed it.

Comment: Removing it of course allows non-unique values. SQLServer is not compliant with the spec here. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166%28v=sql.105%29.aspx and browse to the end of the page to know how to define a unique constraint that ignores null.